# Design workflows for WF4 in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, rule-engine

Our system is based on flows and activities and we want to give the analysts users the opportunity to create dynamics flows (at runtime).  The designer UI based on SL 4.0 .

It looks like WorkflowFoundation is the most valuable solution but we  didn`t find any WF version that fits to SL (to create the xaml in SL).

Any ideas? any other capable engines?

Answer (score 2):

The standard workflow designer is WPF and doesn't work in silverlight. Creating a similar designer will be quite a bit of work. However a simplified designer might do the trick and as a workflows is just xaml which is just XML generating that should be no problem. I guess it depends on the flexibity required.

I am not aware of any 3rd party alternatives out there.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  [Check Here](http://sharedesigner.codeplex.com/releases/view/32301) , it might do the job.

Comment: No, but with minor changes it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Neither WF3 or WF4 execute within the Silverlight client. This includes the designers.