# Need advice: How to implement dynamic workflow creation

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, workflow-foundation-4

I am going to implement a user editable workflow.

They should support if/then clauses and perhaps cycles. The operation Domain is not editable and will contain predefined set of operations like: Send Email, Notify, Message etc. These operations will have parameters.

P.S. If you have experience with implementing something like this, please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:
[Design workflows for WF4 in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452855/design-workflows-for-wf4-in-silverlight)

and this on codeplex:  workflow designer developed in silverlight .

http://sharedesigner.codeplex.com/releases/view/32301

Answer (score 1):

you could use WF ( Workflow Foundation ) to model and execute your workflow.